# Arduino AES128 encryption - C# decryption padding problem

Tags: visual-studio, encryption, arduino, aes

I need a monodirectional encrypted communication. The arduino encrypt the message and send it over serial to C# program for decryption.

The arduino code for encryption looks like:

```
#include <Crypto.h>
#include <base64.hpp>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16
uint8_t key[BLOCK_SIZE] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
uint8_t iv[BLOCK_SIZE] = { 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };

void bufferSize(char* text, int &length)
{
  int i = strlen(text);
  int buf = round(i / BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE;
  length = (buf <= i) ? buf + BLOCK_SIZE : length = buf;
}
void encrypt(char* plain_text, char* output, int length)
{
  byte enciphered[length];
  AES aesEncryptor(key, iv, AES::AES_MODE_128, AES::CIPHER_ENCRYPT);
  aesEncryptor.process((uint8_t*)plain_text, enciphered, length);
  int encrypted_size = sizeof(enciphered);
  char encoded[encrypted_size];
  encode_base64(enciphered, encrypted_size, (unsigned char*)encoded);
  strcpy(output, encoded);
}
```

The encrypted message is:

`jEYGnz3TYm+aWveh8wNATw==`

And the plaintext message is:

`24051984`

On the PC side, i have in Visual Studio next code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace BaseReadSerial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = cBoxComPort.Text;
                serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
                serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
                serialPort1.Open();
                lblStatusCom.Text = "On";
                lblMessage.Text = "I am on!";
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                lblStatusCom.Text = "Off";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                //string mgs1 = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                string mgs1 = "jEYGnz3TYm+aWveh8wNATw==";
                serialPort1.Close();
                lblStatusCom.Text = "Off";
                string base64Decoded;
                byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(mgs1);
                base64Decoded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                //Start
                var str = base64Decoded;
                var aes = new SimpleAES();
                var encryptStr = aes.Encrypt(str);
                var decryptStr = aes.Decrypt(mgs1);
                //End
                lblMessage.Text = decryptStr;

            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = "Off";
        }

        private void lblStatusCom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cBoxComPort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    public class SimpleAES
    {
        private byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        private byte[] vector = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        private readonly ICryptoTransform encryptor;
        private readonly ICryptoTransform decryptor;
        private readonly UTF8Encoding encoder;

        public SimpleAES()
        {
            var rm = new RijndaelManaged();
            encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
            decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
            encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        }

        public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted)));
        }

        public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
        {
            return encoder.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)));
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return Transform(buffer, encryptor);
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return Transform(buffer, decryptor);
        }

        protected byte[] Transform(byte[] buffer, ICryptoTransform transform)
        {

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After a triger condition happened, i receive an error message:

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'`

If i think right, **uint8_t** (Arduino) is same as **byte[]** (Visual Studio C#), or is the error somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong here.

- Arduino: You should be randomly generating an IV every time, and sending along with the message.
- Arduino: You're using `round` on an integer expression, it's just wasteful.  Removing the word `round` won't change any answers (but it will remove floating point math and possibly avoid turning on the floating point part of the chip, saving power).
- Arduino: You're making a base64 output buffer (`encoded`) of the same size as the input.  Base64 grows by 4/3 (`(size + 2) / 3 * 4`), so you're doing a buffer overrun.  Either make the buffer bigger, or simply things and base64-encode directly to `output`.

  - Side point: You aren't accepting bounds for `output`.  Hope it's big enough.
- C#: (You need to read the IV per message once you make the Arduino send it)
- C#: You're saving the encryptor and decryptor once each.  They need to be rebuilt after each operation (to put the IV back).
- Both: A hard-coded key makes for almost no security. You'll want to pursue getting random session keys.  (ECDH Key Agreement / PC sends RSA public key, Arduino makes random AES key, sends it back encrypted with RSA / etc).

Assuming that your input/key/IV/output is as you're running, you've got a bug somewhere in the Arduino code.  According to https://cryptii.com/pipes/W21RJA, the output of `Base64(AES-CBC-Encrypt(key: unhex("01020304050607080901020304050607"), iv: unhex("07060504030201090807060504030201"), message: ASCII("24051984"))` is `pArfBo2HLU9+DXGhFPJDFg==`

When you can get the same answer from something like cryptii.com and your encryption code on the Arduino, you can then move on to the decryption logic (and then random IV).

FWIW, encrypting serial doesn't make a lot of sense to me. There are no untrusted legs, and you can easily monitor for MITM on a 6 foot cable...

Comment: You had right, the problem is on Arduino side, have tested now with a data provided by You. The main goal is to "lock" a software to arduino, because the software is much expensive that an arduino hardware, and i will prevent that chines copiers make a same device as i and use my software. To be say honest, i don't think that a mid size copier company from china will spend much supercomputer CPU time to break my encryption to receive the kays and program it into his arduino copied hardware.